# change the login home page

Tags: 2010, theme, custom-login-page

I have a fba website in `SharePoint 2010` . I want to customize the `login` page according to my website `theme` and add contents to it as well as want to use that login functionality . What should be my approach to achieve this ?

Comment: Any help from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Start from the following article

[Branding Default Login Page for Form Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent)

Find default FBA login page in

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS`

instead of

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\FORMS`

Now apply your custom branding. I have customized it for SharePoint 2013. I hope all the things are same. Just you have to take care of **14** instead of **15**.

[image]